# How to convert from Graphics Object to Base64 String

Tags: c#

How would I convert a `Graphics` object to a `Base64` String in `C#`

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(imageStream, true);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img);
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to serialise the Graphics object so you keep all of it's properties and data? Or do you just care about the image data? (If just the image, why use graphics at all, just convert the image that you already have)

Comment: I found no direct answers online for converting between a Graphics Object to a Base64 string. This question was answered by myself in a Q&A style. I could, of course, update the question example to better reflect the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert between `Graphics`, `Bitmaps` and `Base64 Strings` using MemoryStreams in `C#`

```
//
//Convert Base64 String to Image
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64String);
MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
imageStream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
Image img = Image.FromStream(imageStream, true);

//
// Convert Image to Graphics Object
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img);
graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 3), rectangle);

//
//Convert Graphics Object to Base64String
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
}
```